# I have a hard time with determining the input impedance of the problem shown as well as the equivalent lumped circuit model with this Zin

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, homework

[image]

This is the work I have done so far. I am not confident in my work and was having a hard time with determining the input impedance. If you have a correction or opinion on this work please comment.
[image]

Comment: Show how you worked out your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wavelength is 2e8 /(400e6) = 0.5 m
Hense, the transmission line is 2.4 wavelengths (eq 0.4 wavelengths) and the load is 75 / 50 = 1.5.

So the result is z_nom= 1.04 + 0.41j

[Smithchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBbai.png)